# Visual Studio Toolbox - close toolbox shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, toolbox

I wonder if there is a way of confirming selection of a tool from MS VS Toolbox / close toolbox. The opposite of:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> .. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

and

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

What I find really annoying is when I have to add an association between two entities in model designer, and the one that I want to start with is hidden behind toolbox.

If so, I have to use e.g. scrollbar to make toolbox loose focus.

Is there a way to confirm that I want to use selected control and hide the toolbox?

(like <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd> in VS6) ?

Comment: Just make sure the toolbox doesn't overlap anything.  Click the pin.

Comment: This is not an option for me and not an answer to my question.